# I need Highchart watermark image when i download highchart

Tags: highcharts

I am using HighCharts Javascript library for a web application. I need Highchart watermark image when i download Highchart.
I am using normal hicgchart code.
[Code here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-stacked/)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked bar chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    reversed: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
  }, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
  }, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by download?

Comment: image download. like as png, jpeg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**please use this code**

```js
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        events: {
            load: function() {
                this.renderer.image('https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1r9X.png', 200, 20, 163, 187)
                .attr({
         zIndex:1000  })
                  .add();
            }
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }],
    
    exporting: {
        enableImages: true
    }

});
```

```css
image{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script><div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can watermark a picture only when it is downloaded by including that in the [**exporting options**](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting), like this:

```
exporting: {
  chartOptions: {
    chart: {
      plotBackgroundImage: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1r9X.png'
    }
  }
}
```

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked bar chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    reversed: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
  }, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
  }, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
  }],
  exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
      chart: {
        plotBackgroundImage: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1r9X.png'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Working JSFiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/acL4z2su/2/

Comment: thanks for your replay, but watermark not fully shown in your output. chart pillers hide the watermark

Comment: if a stacked area chart generating. background image not fully showing

Answer (score 0):

A watermark on screen where you can interact with the chart (based on a previous answer) can come from:

```
//
//  add a watermark (where template is the highchart object I'm building)
//
template.chart.events = {
    load: function() {
        this.renderer.image('https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1r9X.png')
        .attr({
    zIndex:1000, x:'10%', y:'10%', width:'80%',height:'80%', style:'pointer-events:none' })
          .add();
    }
};
```